# Bounded sets equivalent definition

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, predicate-logic

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $E\subset X$. I have two definitions of a *bounded* set, I want to prove they are equivalent.

**Definition 1:**
$\exists M:\exists q\in X:\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M$

**Definition 2:**
$\exists M:\forall p,q\in E:d(p,q)<M$

**Proof:**

($\implies$)

1. $\exists M:\exists q\in X:\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M$
2. $\exists q\in X:\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M_{0}$
3. $\forall p\in E:d(p,q_{0})<M_{0}$
4. $E\subset N_{M_{0}}(q_{0})$ [a neighborhood around $q_{0}$ of radius $M_{0}$]
5. $\forall p,q\in E:d(p,q)<2M_{0}$ [Thanks to A.P. and Hagen for this]
6. $\exists M:\forall p,q\in E:d(p,q)<M$

($\Longleftarrow$)

1. $\exists M:\forall p,q\in E:d(p,q)<M$
2. $\forall p,q\in E:d(p,q)<M_{0}$
3. $\forall p\in E:d(p,q_{0})<M_{0}$
4. $\exists q\in E:\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M_{0}$
5. $\exists q\in X:\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M_{0}$
6. $\exists M:\exists q\in X:\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M$

Comment: Note that the definitions are only equivalent if $X\ne \emptyset$. It is more or less because of this that from 2 to 3 in the second part you have some problem. - Also: Are aou *required* to write proofs as pure sequences of formulas? A more wordy proof might ve much more legible (and at least you might want to add the rules you used for your interferences)

Comment: Thanks Hagen. I'm learning predicate logic, so I revisit these kind of demonstrations to practice. Very interesting point the fact that $X\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hagen von Eitzen said in his comment, the two definitions are equivalent only as long as $X \neq \varnothing$.
Other than that, the $(\Leftarrow)$ part is correct, but the $(\Rightarrow)$ part is not. Namely, when going from 4 to 5 you should use $d(p,q) \leq d(p,q_0) + d(q,q_0) < 2M_0$ instead of $d(p,q) < M_0$.

---

From your question it isn't clear if you actually *need* to use logic formalism. If you don't, then you could write the proof in a more legible way, as I do below.

Here we will assume $E \neq \varnothing$ for simplicity: $\varnothing$ is always bounded by definition 2 and is bounded by definition 1 as long as $X \neq \varnothing$.

$\mathbf{1 \Rightarrow 2}:$ Let $M,q$ be as in definition 1. Then for every $p_1,p_2 \in E$ we have
$$
d(p_1,p_2) \leq d(p_1,q) + d(q,p_2) < 2M
$$
by the triangle inequality. Thus $E$ satisfies definition 2 with $M' = 2M$.

$\mathbf{2 \Rightarrow 1}:$ Let $M$ be as in definition 2 and fix a $q \in E$. Then by definition 2
$$
d(p,q) < M
$$
for every $p \in E$. Thus $E$ satisfies definition 1, too.

Comment: Thank you A.P. $X=\emptyset$ is not bounded by definition 1 because, if we expand it we get: $\exists M:\exists q: q\in X \wedge (\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M)$. Since $q\in X$ is false, then $q\in X \wedge (\forall p\in E:d(p,q)<M)$ is false. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, although maybe you can just say that $\exists q \in X$ is false because $X = \varnothing$, thus the whole formula is false.